# Access "thing" value in ng-repeat "thing in things" using $filter from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to move a $filter from my view to a controller in angularjs.

Right now I have something like (simplified to hopefully only show relevant stuff):

```
//view
    ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: 'something'" where the "something" is a property of "thing". 

//controller
$scope.things = $filter('filter', {whatGoesHere?:something});
```

How would I access that same nested property from the controller? I'm using firebase to each "thing" key is a unique identifier.

Thanks.

Edit: My object looks like this:

```
things: {
    thingID1: {
      something: 'value';
    },
    thingID2: {
     something: 'value'
    },
   ...
}
```

Comment: After doing some more research, it looks like I need to use something like this: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/bee266e31aa60cb0eed6 but I can't figure out exactly how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You would call it like this:

```
$scope.things = $filter('filter')(unfilteredThings, 'something');
```

If you want to filter on a specific property, you can do:

```
$scope.things = $filter('filter')(unfilteredThings, { thePropertyName: 'something' });
```

Comment: That looks like the correct answer but I am doing something wrong. I added an edit to my post that shows the structure of my object. It seems like I can't get to the nested, uniqueID values.

Comment: The `filter` filter operates on arrays and your `things` variable isn't an array, so that's probably the problem. So the `something` in your example would match up with `uniqueID1` and you want to get the `{ thing: 'value' }` for that? Is that what you're trying to do? Or are you trying to find the item where `something` matches `value`?

Comment: I only understand what's happening when it's in the view so I will describe it like that: The "something" would be thing.something which is one level deeper into the object "things". "thing in things" iterates over "things" which gives me the uniqueID ("thing") and then I can access the nested property of "something" to use as a filter. The filter would show thing.something in things. (sorry about how confusing this sounds) EDIT: also, I updated the example object to be much more clear. I'm trying to iterate through "thing in things" and access the "something" property.

Comment: Also, I should add, "things" is an instance of $firebaseArray so it should work as an array.